Как привязать обьект Django models к JavaScript?
Мне нужно передать данные из django.models в JS для их дальнейшей обработки.
JS скрипт я могу разместить в самом html, но мне нужно, чтобы было наглядное разделение JavaScript от HTMl. Поэтому я добавляю скрипт в html через src. Однако, если добавлять код в сам html:
<script>
    let all = "{{ all }}";
</script>

то у меня доступна переменная all из отдельного скрипта, но в этой переменной находится всякая несуразица:
&lt;QuerySet [(1, &#x27;Генерация текста&#x27;, &#x27;text&#x27;, &#x27;&#x27;, &#x27;content/image_1mjkSb1.png&#x27;, &#x27;Chat-GPT&#x27;, &#x27;https://openai.com/chatgpt&#x27;, &#x27;1&#x27;), (2, &#x27;Игры на базе текста&#x27;, &#x27;text&#x27;, &#x27;&#x27;, &#x27;content/image_HFWDR3G.png&#x27;, &#x27;Chat-GPT&#x27;, &#x27;https://openai.com/chatgpt&#x27;, &#x27;1&#x27;)]&gt;

может, можно эту инфу как то раскодировать, или преобразовать?
Где-то видел что можно через for перебрать, и просто удалить все ненужные символы и очистить от мусора, но я сомневаюсь что это будет стабильно работать
Хотелось бы понять, как же сделать это именно из отдельного файла
